# Spring Webflux 2.4.4 - Metrics growing infinitely over time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

Small question regarding SpringBoot Webflux project, and some metrics growing too rapidly over time please.

our web application is using Netty and we declare a bean as follow:

```
 @Bean
    public NettyServerCustomizer nettyServerCustomizer() {
        return httpServer -> httpServer.metrics(true, () -> new MicrometerChannelMetricsRecorder("name", "name"));
    }
```

Our web application is exposing a /metrics endpoint for polling.
We have many interesting metrics, would like to keep them.

Really, we just counted the total numbers of metrics, on poll 1, we had some 300, one minutes later, on poll 2, we had some 1300, then some 2300, etc, as you can imagine, after a day of app up, this endpoints response and network byte sent goes to the roof.

I noticed four particular metrics that are growing indefinitely, and at a very fast rate.

```
 tls_handshake_time_seconds_count
 data_received_bytes_count
 data_received_bytes_max
 data_received_bytes_sum
```

Every time we poll /metrics, those four metrics combine will add 1000 more entries, each minute.
This is alarming as the polling response time keeps increasing, the number of bytes sent as well.

May I ask how to disable those four particular metrics please? I would like to keep everything else untouched.

To be honest, I found the metrics quite useful, as we have an alert setup when the SSL handshake time is high, and this was very useful.

Unfortunately, the growth is too brutal. I would like to ask:

- How to disable those four? (if possible not to disable inadvertently some other useful metrics)
- For the future, how to keep them enabled, but not have this uncontrollable growth of new metrics as time goes.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Indeed, I did not provided any snippet, because I am not finding  any code that would write such metrics. Maybe it is some default out of the box metrics provided by Netty or SpringBoot

Comment: Please provide at least how you enable the metrics

Comment: Hello @VioletaGeorgieva, you are correct, apologies not to have done so before, let me update the question

Comment: original question updated

Comment: do you know which tag on these metrics is causing the growth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. How to disable specific metrics**

You can use a `MeterFilter` to disable specific metrics by name. You need to register your `MeterFilter` as a spring managed bean

```
    @Bean
    public MeterFilter myMeterFilter() {
        return MeterFilter.deny(id -> id.getName().startsWith("data_received_bytes") ||
                id.getName().startsWith("tls_handshake_time")
        );
    }
```

**2. How to control/limit the number of tags on a metric**

You can also use a `MeterFilter` to achieve this. You can use a `MeterFilter` to set a cardinality limit on specific tags of specific metrics, allowing you to limit the growth of these metrics and limit the impact they can have on your application

```
    @Bean
    public MeterFilter myMeterFilter() {
        return MeterFilter.maximumAllowableTags("data_received_bytes", "tagWithHighCardinality", 100,
                MeterFilter.deny());
    }
```

The two solutions above are workarounds to the issues you are observing and you ultimately might want to understand **why** the cardinality of these specific metrics are increasing over time.

[MeterFilter Docs](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_denyaccept_meters)

Comment: I am still having a hard time understanding the root cause, but the explanations given here, both solutions works. Accepting. 

So far, to answer to your question, I have a tag which is a hostname for the TLS Handshake, and it seems the IPs + port combinations grows indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the API that `HttpServer` exposes i.e.

[metrics(boolean, Function)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServer.html#metrics-boolean-java.util.function.Function-)

```
HttpServer.create().metrics(true, Function)
```

This will enable the default integration with `Micrometer`

Or

[metrics(boolean, Supplier, Function)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/http/server/HttpServer.html#metrics-boolean-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.Function-)

```
HttpServer.create().metrics(true, CustomHttpServerMetricsRecorder::new, Function)
```

This exposes to you the `HttpServer` metrics. Note that in this API, `CustomHttpServerMetricsRecorder` implements `HttpServerMetricsRecorder` and not as in your example `MicrometerChannelMetricsRecorder`.

Consider checking the [reference guide](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_metrics_4) and the recommendations there.